# Cómo modificar correctamente una fecha en Java/AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, date, studio

Luego de seleccionar una fecha, la idea es que aumente por defecto 7 días extras. El problema es cuando son días cercanos a fin de mes y queda: Fecha inicio 25/4/22 y **fecha fin 2/4/22**. Suma los días, pero queda en el mismo mes. Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Saludos.

```
calendario.set(year, month, day);

dateFechaDesdeSeleccionado = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                dateFechaDesdeFormatoSeleccionado = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
                btnFechaDesde.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><big>" + "Fecha desde" + "</big></b>" + "<br />" +
                        "<small>" + dateFechaDesdeSeleccionado + "</small>" + "<br />"));

                calendario.add(calendario.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
                year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                dateFechaHastaSeleccionado = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                dateFechaHastaFormatoSeleccionado = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
                btnFechaHasta.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><big>" + "Fecha hasta" + "</big></b>" + "<br />" +
                        "<small>" + dateFechaHastaSeleccionado + "</small>" + "<br />"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Para sumar días y que se tengan en cuenta los cambios de mes y año lo tienes que hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
 calendario.add(calendario.DATE, 7); //Suma 7 días
```